# Use asp.net fileupload to attach multiple files to email without uploading files to server

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I guess this would qualify as a rhetorical question.  I'm posting it because there was no single answer that dealt with my issue, and I had to cobble together the answer from several sources. I figured it might be helpful to consolidate.

Using Visual Basic, I needed to allow our web application users to send us files and image files to support other information entered on the standard user interface.

Our management does not want any file uploading to our web server. They want everything to go through email, in order to restrict access to the server and because we already pay for email virus and security screening.

I want the users to be able to send multiple files.

Since we want explanations of what they are sending us, that information is captured in a rich text editor and is used as the message body.

We want to keep it in the most basic form possible - no javascript, jquery, no AJAX, LINQ or other Microsoft enhancements.

Answer (score 0):

So, here's what we did.

1. Used the ASP FileUpload object.
2. Used the .NET 4.5 framework, which is the lowest one that allows multiple file selection
3. Treat each selected file as an HTTPPostedFile (System.Web)
4. Converted each file to a FileStream
5. Attached the FileStreams to the email.

The ASP coding -

```
    <form runat="server" id="form1">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6"><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblWelcomeMssg" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <asp:FileUpload ID="selectedFiles" AllowMultiple="true" runat="server" /><br />
        <div class="col-sm-3"><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblStatus" Text="" ForeColor="Red" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-1"><br /><br /></div>
    </div>       
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-10"><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="rteBody" TextMode="MultiLine" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-1"><br /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-1"><asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSend" Text="Send" /></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2"><asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnClear" Text="Clear" /></div>
    </div>
```

And then all the action happens after selection of multiple files, when the "Send" button is clicked.  Note: ContactInfo is just a vb class I created for convenient handling of user information.

Codebehind -

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Mail
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Web

Public Class SendUsTheFiles
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        If Session("AUTHENTICATED_USER") Then
            lblWelcomeMssg.Text = "{Welcome... and instructions....}<br /><br />"
        Else
            Response.Redirect("SignIn.aspx")
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub btn_Send_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSend.Click
    Dim fileSendMail As New MailMessage
    Dim usrID As String = Session.Item("USER_ID")
    Dim IndEmailInfo As New ContactInfo

    IndEmailInfo = ContactGet(usrID)
' ContactGet is a global function that retrieves user name and email information from our SQL database   

    Dim FromAdd As New MailAddress(IndEmailInfo.emailAddr, IndEmailInfo.Name)

    Dim oServer As New SmtpClient
    Dim txtHtmlBody As String = rteBody.Text

    Dim fileCount As Integer = 0
    Dim ToAdd As New MailAddress("officeFolk@ourorg.org", "Customer Services")
    Dim ccAdd As New MailAddress("admin@ourorg.org", "Polo Holeset")
    Dim objMail As New MailMessage(FromAdd, ToAdd)
    objMail.CC.Add(ccAdd)

    If selectedFiles.HasFiles = True Then
        For Each uploadedFile As HttpPostedFile In selectedFiles.PostedFiles
            Try
                Dim strFileName As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile.FileName)

                Dim attachment As New Attachment(uploadedFile.InputStream, strFileName)

                objMail.Attachments.Add(attachment)
                fileCount = fileCount + 1
            Catch

            End Try
        Next
    End If

    oServer.Host = "mail.ourorg.org"
    oServer.UseDefaultCredentials = True

    objMail.Subject = "File submission"
    objMail.IsBodyHtml = True
    objMail.Body = txtHtmlBody
    Try
        oServer.Send(objMail)
        lblStatus.Text = fileCount.ToString & " files successfully sent."
        rteBody.Text = String.Empty

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub

...............
```